# Django equivalent of Rails application.html.erb?

Tags: django

Is there a shared "master" layout in Django for HTML files similar to Rails `application.html.erb`? If not, is there a best practice on how to go about creating one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Django, the best practise is to use three levels of template using [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/#id1).

I quote the [django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html#template-inheritance) to explain you:

> You can use as many levels of inheritance as needed. One common way of
> using inheritance is the following three-level approach:
>
> 1. Create a base.html template that holds the main look and feel of
>    your site. This is the stuff that rarely, if ever, changes.
> 2. Create a base_SECTION.html template for each “section” of your site
>    (e.g., base_photos.html and base_forum.html). These templates
>    extend base.html and include section-specific styles/design.
> 3. Create individual templates for each type of page, such as a forum
>    page or a photo gallery. These templates extend the
>    appropriate section template.
>
> This approach maximizes code reuse and makes it easy to add items to
> shared areas, such as section-wide navigation.

Comment: Thanks. On a side note, do people still reference the Django book often? I skipped over it because I saw it was last updated in 2009... was wondering if it is still a reliable reference.

Comment: Even if the Django book is a bit old, it is still quite useful. However, there are some things which are not up to date so you have to be careful.